# Why is the time-complexity for modulus operation constant?

Tags: time-complexity

I am working through *Cracking the Coding Interview*, and I am unsure of an example on time-complexity. They provide this code to determine if a number is prime:

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int x = 2; x * x <= n; x++) {
        if (n % x == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Later they say "The work inside the for loop is constant".  Why is run-time for modulus operator constant? Why does it not depend on n?

Answer (score 1):

The key part of the statement there is *inside* the for loop. All that's happening is a a modulo operation. Inside the *function itself* the time complexity depends on n

Comment: Why is the time complexity of the modulo operation, n%x, independent of n? Does 10^10 % 7 take the same amount of time as 10%7?

Comment: A modulo operation is a fairly low-level operation carried out by the registers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register). In a 64-bit system, the registers are 64-bits wide. Since the parameter here is an int (32 bits most likely), the operation will be carried out on all the bits in the register, regardless of their value (0 or 1).

Comment: Also  10^10 (10000000000) is too large to fit in a integer (max is 2147483647)

Comment: I think I understand. I would not have thought of considering the hardware for time-complexity issues. (And now I have better understanding of why multiplication/addition are considered constant-time operations, too.)  Thanks!